# Why does PHP use so much memory during sqlsrv_fetch_object?

Tags: php, sql, out-of-memory

I've been stress testing some SVG image code using lots of data (almost 200,000 records from the SQL Server DB) and it kept running out of memory. Using xdebug to trace with the mem_delta enabled I get:

```
   14.1789   59408336     +520             -> sqlsrv_fetch_object()
   14.1790   59408856     +520             -> sqlsrv_fetch_object()
   14.1792   59409376     +520             -> sqlsrv_fetch_object()
   14.1793   59409896     +520             -> sqlsrv_fetch_object()
   14.1794   59410416     +520             -> sqlsrv_fetch_object()
```

This is the code:

```
$rows = array();

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

The schema for the database table has three columns A, B and C (I renamed them to try and reduce the memory usage, saved myself about 20 bytes per record), that are bigint, int, and int respectively.

For the data itself I would only expect 16 bytes to be used per record, plus 3 bytes for the object property labels, and some more bytes that PHP uses to manage it's objects. This should still fall vastly short of 520 bytes though.

I'm thinking maybe it's the act of extending the array, yet that doesn't explain why it's extending it by 520 bytes every time a new item is appended, and why it doesn't shrink at all once it's done.

Why would PHP be allocating so much memory when it's not needed? And what could I do to reduce it?

Comment: You underestimate size of PHP datastructures. Read http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: Naktibalda: Wow that's....astounding. Can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark this question answered?